# Remove precision from divide

Tags: c++

well basically if I write something like this -

```
float a = 0;
a = (float) 1/5;
a += (float) 1/9;
a += (float) 1/100;
```

It will automatically decrase precision to 2 digits after comma, but I need to have 5 digits after comma, is it available to create, so it displays 5 digits? With setprecision(5) it, just shows 00000 after comma.

It get's all data from input file just fine.

Comment: when are you calling the `setPrecision()`?

Comment: Okay, but how then I should write, to show the divised numbers with precision 5 numbers after comma? Well I mean, I must output it in the end in file, and in file it must show the result with 5 precision after comma, so it would be something like 0.51251 (that is different example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give 5 digits after comma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argi, char** argc) {
       float a = 0;
       a = (float) 1/5;
        a += (float) 1/9;
        a += (float) 1/100;

        cout << setprecision(5) << a << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

if you want to have always 5 digits on output, maybe use this:

```
cout << setprecision(5) << setfill ('0')<< setw(5) << a << endl;
```

Comment: it only gives out 2 numbers after comma

Comment: Lol, had issue in code, but thanks you made me think that fault is in my code.

Answer (score 4):

`setprecision` do not modify value. It's only display desired precision when you using `ofstream`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use setprecision like this:

```
cout << setprecision (5) << a << endl;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/

**EDIT**: I haven't used C++ in a while but you may be getting some problems because you are doing `integer` division and then casting the result to a `float`. Try doing it like this instead to force a `float` division:

```
a+=1.0f/100;
```

Comment: So your final output value for `a` is `0.00000` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have some reading to do:

http://www.google.com/?q=what+every+programmer+should+know+about+floating+point